# Status of 422 - CloudFront to ELB connection

Tags: nginx, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb

I have created two EC2 instances and put them on Loadbalancer.

By using the Application LoadBalancer URL I am able to login that EC2 instance and doing all.

But While I configure Cloudfront to ELB

1. Using Cloudfront SSL
2. Cloud front To ELB connection on port 80

and hit CloudFront URL on the browser I am able to get the login page of my application.
While a sign in to my application it will give me an error like:

```
sign_in:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 ()
```

My Cloudfront settings is as below:

[image]

*I am using the Nginx server.

In Nginx, I have also configured:

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
```

**Question:  Is there any missing setting in CloudFront or Nginx server?**